# ubuntu laptop to win7 laptop music transfer

Tags: windows, files, connection, transfer, firewire

What is the easiest way to connect my ubuntu laptop to a win7 laptop to pull music and pics off the win7 laptop?
I installed Ubuntu on my new computer as the primary os and I want to pull my music, pics and some docs off my old one in the easiest way possible.

Comment: How big is this music directory? Do you have a flash drive? Do you have a network that both computers can connect through?

Comment: @Subcomfreak my 1st question would be... are the 2 in the same network?

Comment: I have about 1500 songs, and a few hundred pictures, about 150 pics.  I couldn't figure out how to connect the ubuntu computer to the network.  I thought I'd use a firewire but I just installed ubuntu for the first time and I'm new to this arena.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect both computers in hotspot or a command LAN.

Then, you need to share folder with your files from windows computer.

Then, from Ubuntu

1. Open File Manager (`nautilus`) i.e Open your home folder.
2. From **Menu > Go > Network** in Nautilus, or from left sidepane, click on **Browse Network**.

   [image: Browse Network]
3. You can find your Windows share in a folder named **Windows Network**.[image]
4. Open your shared folder, enter windows username and password if asked.
5. Now, you can copy your files as you wish.

Comment: Ok.  I couldn't figure out the ubuntu side.  I got a call just now so I gotta go but, I will try this as soon as I can and get back to you guys.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @donna Refer to the edited answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the link had the same issue and see whats the solution he thought of using

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/152326/how-do-i-share-my-files-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu
```

Comment: My search didn't turn up that link.  I'll check it out as soon as I can.  Gotta go to work right now.  Thank you for the link.