# Drive not showing up

Tags: mount, filesystem

Every time I start my ubuntu and do a "ls" in "/media/my_username" directory my drive D: is not showing up,but after when I enter the D: using GUI and doing a ls it shows up,can any one help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automount my Windows partition at boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123234/how-to-automount-my-windows-partition-at-boot)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not set your drive to mount automatically.

You can do it by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`.

When you click your drive in file manager, it gets mounted.